# JQuery Webcam Plugin (or other) to display SERVER's webcam image through ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, webcam

Is there a way to have the plugin access a server's webcam and have it display that image over the web application as opposed to using the user's camera? I'm trying to create a web application for video surveillance and I wanted to just have a feed of the server's cameras to display for the user, whether it be a still image or live video feed, i'll take either.

I'm kind of new with ASP.NET and JQuery in general, so if you could kindly explain it to me in simplest terms (without omitting anything) as to how I should approach in doing this. I want to be able to do this through ASP.NET Web Application, or if really possible ASP.NET MVC (I know this is harder). If possible, could anyone point me to the right direction as to how to integrate these things (step by step preferred).

Kind of TL;DR, I need a way, even if it's not JQuery Webcam Plugin, to implement a video or still image feed of the SERVER's cameras, so that any user can access and see THOSE cameras as opposed to their own webcams. I would like to put this into a ASP.NET web application or if really possible an ASP.NET MVC Application. Any re-directs or feedback and/or suggestions to approach this is appreciated. Remember, this is for a video surveillance program, but for the most simplest terms I just want to be able to see a feed from the webcam (I don't care if it's still image or video feed). I just want this to be able to have a video feed for use in a mobile site or web application. The point is to make a web application and have it compatible with a mobile device.

Most of the questions here are how you can enable the USER to take a picture from their own webcam and save it onto the server, but that's not what I want. I've done some similar searches around (but most are outdated or pertain to the usage above that i don't want).

Thank you.

Comment: Could you narrow it down to an specific issue? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Um, i've tried the JQuery Webcam Plugin a little bit, using some tutorials around the web but it only seems like it's concerned with using the user's webcam and uploading the picture to the server. The only issue I want/have is to be able to implement ANY webcam image/feed on my web application for mobile viewing or just on the web application. I'd prefer a still image feed (like a dynamic webcam image), which I did search and it seems to not work.

Answer (score 1):

A true solution would be very time consuming to write and I don't have your specific hardware so I'm not going to try, but here's the way I would break down the task to accomplish it on my own.

1) Get the server webcam stream to be readable in your own .NET application, probably having it be able to export images.

2) Adjust that application so it overwrites the same image continuously in your webserver directory.

3) use jquery to just refresh the image on the page in time with the frequency your camera updates the images on the server.

Without setting up a streaming media server you probably aren't going to be streaming video through the web.  jQuery is a client-side only framework so you can't access any hardware on the server with it directly, so you'll have to handle that with .NET.

Comment: That sounds exactly what I need. I'm sorry for being very vague and noobish about it, but could you suggest how I should go about with step 1) and 2) of your suggestion? I'm interested in the methods that would be able to do that (sorry i'm still learning). As far as the Jquery stuff go, since it's a little advanced I don't think I need to include that, I would just be better off having an image display and change everytime the page is refreshed.

thank you for your help!

Comment: I can't really help you with 1 or 2, but as a budding programmer, you'll need to learn that google is your best friend.  I would start by googling how to read from your webcam with .NET, ideally you'll be able to intuit how to get it into an image from there, then saving is as simple as calling the save function of the System.Drawing.Image type.